# Change the user Apache runs as

Tags: apache, php, root

Need help to create a new user to apache web server and assign root privileges to newly created user. Or how to login as root user in apache server because following php script showing you are logged in as

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

> **nobody**.

Comment: This one probably belongs to either ServerFault or StackOverflow.

Comment: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=372
I'll write this as an answer if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Hipp0 - not StackOverflow

Comment: @Mark if not StackOverflow then?? I am logged in in system as root. I started xampp server as root e.g: sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start. But When I execute < ?php echo whoami; ?> it shows me nobody instead root.........

Comment: Try ServerFault - note that nobody is the correct result - so that apache by default has no permissions to affect the system

Comment: Hey mark I know that as the nobody user logged in I can't do anything with system. But I need to access some system folders/files, for that I need permissions/privileges. So how can I obtain these? Whether I have to run apache as root user or create a new user and assign all privileges that a root user have?

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't a good reason to run your web server as root. It opens you up to all kinds of potential abuse. OS X defaults to running the service as a severely under privileged user to protect you.

### Don't make these changes unless you're absolutely certain you know what you're doing!

The `httpd.conf` file for the default Apache2 installation that comes with OS X can be found in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Before you make any changes to this file *BACK IT UP*! That way you can get back to a sane starting place if you make a catastrophically bad change.

Open the file in a text editor and look for the following lines:

```
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch...
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www
```

The `_www` user/group is the default for OS X. If you want to run the server as root you'll need to change this to the appropriate user. For root:

```
User root
Group wheel
```

The plist that describes the Apache service to [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) is at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` -- OS X runs any launchd runs daemons described in this location as root so the server starts with sufficient privledges to change context to another user.

Once you've made the changes, restart Apache with:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

and you should be running as root.

Again: **BE CAREFUL DOING THIS!**

Comment: Sir it was glad for me to see your answer. I am using ubuntu server 11.10. I understand the risk to run apache as root, but I am a student so wants to gain more and more knowledge. I have installed xampp server in **/opt** and my **httpd** file is in **/opt/lampp/etc**.
By following your answer I editted the **httpd** file.

Comment: In ubuntu we have **nobody** as default user and group. So following your answer I have changed **nobody** to root in both user and group. The secong step: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist , I couldn't understand. I have searched **plist** in my **/opt** directory but I couldn't found. Instead of **plist** I found **PropList.txt**.

Comment: @Alee my plist stuff only applies if you're running on OS X. Skip that for Ubuntu. This got posted on AskDifferent so it's implied you're using Apple OS -- hence my OS X-specific answer.

Comment: @IanC. I followed your instructions but i'm kinda stuck.. can you help me out with my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671647/modifying-apache-config-to-allow-mobile-device-to-access-my-site-on-local-networ) here?